# report performance when using with clause

Tags: oracle11g

I working on a fairly simple report based on two columns in a table below
If is_sender is true, add a row "sender" to the report
If both are on, add two records to the report
So for the below data the results are:

```
sender, Robert
receiver,Robert
receiver,Marco
```

I have achieved the desired report using the "with clause" and union of the results but its performance is really bad,

Is there a way to do the same using Analytical function, or some better way?

```
create table users_table(
    name varchar2(10),
    is_sender char(1),
    is_receiver char(1)
)

insert into users_table values('Robert','y','n');
insert into users_table values('Marco','y','y');

create or replace  view users_view ("role", "name") as 
(
   select role,name from (
    with sender_reciver_view as (select name,is_sender,is_receiver from users_table)
select 'sender' as role,name from sender_reciver_view where is_sender='y'
   union all
select 'receiver',name from sender_reciver_view where is_receiver='y')
)
```

Comment: AFAIK a common table expression (i.e. using `WITH`) should not really affect performance adversely.  But have you thought about putting an index on the `is_sender` and `is_receiver` columns?  This might make the two parts of the `UNION` much faster.

Comment: why do you need `WITH` clause here? The `UNION ALL` is enough, right?

Comment: It seems `with` is irrelevant in this case, and not even required in your query. This appears to be a performance question, and as stated the most obvious performance improvement would be to ensure you have correct indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in your example Marco should have had two lines, right?

```
select
  m.role,
  ut.name
from users_table ut
  join (
    select 'sender' as role from dual union all
    select 'receiver' from dual
  ) m
  on (m.role = 'sender' and ut.is_sender = 'y')
  or (m.role = 'receiver' and ut.is_receiver = 'y');
```

Result:

```
ROLE     NAME
sender   Robert
sender    Marco
receiver  Marco
```